# Adding columns to DB after publishing using EF CodeF and mvc nugget Scaffold

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, code-first

I have created a web site using mvc 3 and Ef code first , now after publishing the site and it's DB  I have found out that I need to add a new columns to one of my DB table,
(the DB already has a lot of data in it )
should I add the columns  direct to the DB  or should I add to the class? 
(just a simple string with get and set)
And how can I do it without losing my data in the DB ?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the columns to the class should be enough. Evidence you can find [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/07/27/code-first-migrations-walkthrough-of-august-2011-ctp.aspx).

> Here is the full list of changes that migrations can take care of automatically:
>
> - Adding a property or class
>
>   - Nullable columns will be assigned a value of null for any existing rows of data
>   - Non-Nullable columns will be assigned the CLR default for the given data type for any existing rows of data
> - Renaming a property or class
>
>   - See ‘Renaming Properties & Classes’ for the additional steps required here
> - Renaming an underlying column/table without renaming the property/class 
>     (Using data annotations or the fluent API)
>
>   - Migrations can automatically detect these renames without additional input
> - Removing a property
>
>   - See ‘Automatic Migrations with Data Loss’ section for more information

I suggest you to add the columns direct to the DB **and** to the class, and test it on the local machine.